# Linux scheduler operation on a multi-core system

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

Can a Linux scheduler in the kernel run simultaneously on multiple cores? Or is there only a single scheduler which will run on each processer as and when needed?

Comment: The schedular is a piece of code which runs on all CPUs/cores.  What is the goal of asking such a question:  Perhaps that would provide more informative answers.

Comment: Found the answer. Each processor runs a schedule() function independently. However, each core exchanges data with the others.

Comment: I am trying to deactivate tasks from inside of the scheduler. I need to know that if I am in the context of a scheduler on one processor, can the scheduler run on other processor too and change the state of task running on that processor?

Comment: I am sure it could.  That is why there is a spinlock protecting the scheduler structures.

Answer (score 1):

OS usually runs on a specific processor, default being core-0. However, kernel or the scheduler can start kernel threads to handle OS operations and each CPU is seen as a separate data structure (i.e., run-queue) from the scheduler perspective. There is a single scheduler, but it is not a single process.